# Ajax postback not working for bytes array

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am having issue figuring out on how to post `bytes[]`array to the actionresult inside the controller using ajax.

It is giving me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

Here is my code for the actionresult

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult GetPDF(string id)
{
     var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(id);
     byte[] byteArray = bytes;
     return byteArray != null
       ? new FileContentResult(byteArray, "application/pdf")
       : null;
}
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').on('click', function () {            
        $.ajax({
            url: '/BillPayment/GetPDF',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: @Model.ROIAgreementApplication.ToString() }, 
            success: function (response) {
                //process
            }
        });
    });        
});
```

`@Model.ROIAgreementApplication` is an `Byte Array` which am trying to process in my actionresult.

However it is giving me an error at this point in the ajax
`data: { id: @Model.ROIAgreementApplication.ToString() },` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Please advice?

Comment: `@Model.ROIAgreementApplication.ToString()` is invalid javascript/jquery syntax

Comment: You are missing, the single quotes `id:'@Model.ROIAgreementApplication.ToString()'`